# Using Ipod touch at work: Can they tell what I am looking at?

Tags: network, privacy

I use my Ipod touch at work and connect to the company network Wifi. I know they can tell what apps I am using, but will they be able to tell what I am doing in those apps? (Safari? Reddit?)

Also, will they be able to connect my ipod touch to me? I have made no attempt to conceal my identity on my ipod touch.

Thanks in advance for your time, I see similar things posted but I was curious about my scenario. (this is a pretty big corporation)

Comment: It really depends on the level of monitoring in place and the configuration of your company wifi. Based on your description of it being a "pretty big corporation", then probably they can. Your question lacks details so updating it with more technical details will result in better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes, it is possible for the Access Point owner to monitor which sites you connect to. It is also possible for them to work out that the IPod Touch is yours either through sniffing HTTP traffic or by monitoring the devices location and usage time compared to your building access records and desk location.

If you need to install any app or certificate to connect to your corporate WiFi it is far easier for them to do this.

Given it is possible, are they, is a different question. Most company IT departments are not interested in tracking down what sites you are on, specially on your own devices.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a big company is supposed to have written policy about internet usage. You should read these policies carefully if you are concerned about privacy.

If they can tell what you are doing?

It depends, surely they can log all the web pages you have opened but in https pages they can't know what are you doing since communication is encrypted. For example they know you are in facebook but they don't know to which photo you hit like. They know you are in reddit, or what subbreddit you have opened but they cannot intercept your messages or comments.

Are they able to connect your ipod to you?

It depends in which way the network is configured. If it is a public network (*everyone puts the wireless password and are connected to internet*) then they don't know its you, but they can identify that it is a apple device, and other device information which might leads them to you. If its not a public network that means that your device MAC address was preregistred in a dhcp server which release the IP address you have. If its like this than the IT guys surely knows the ipod belongs to you.